# Double Wifi on ubuntu - Assign specific interface name for specific adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, lsusb

There are two USB ports being used.

This is what I want to do -

```
Wifi Adpater X - USB Port A - wlan0 - connects to network N1
Wifi Adpater Y - USB Port B - wlan1 - connects to network N2
```

I am able to associate wlan0 to network N1 and wlan1 to network N2. But the two adapters X and Y are different. X is more capable than the Y (in terms of range, quality etc). I want the adapter X to always be associated to wlan0 and the adapter Y to wlan1. It should not matter when I connect those adapters to odroid or in which order I connect them.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You're using a Ubuntu respin and not an official Ubuntu system*

Comment: The Odroid is not important. Changing the question